# Rename a file but keeping the orginal creation, modification time in UNIX

Tags: unix, solaris, file-rename

Is there any way to rename a file while keeping the original creation / modification/ read time?
This is in Solaris.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with `mv`. However, you can with `cp -p`; copy the file to a new name, then delete the original. The `-p` flag preserves timestamps.

You will get a new inode though... something you wouldn't with `mv`

Comment: Thanks for that, really quick answer too

Answer (score 2):

In a variation on the theme suggested by others:

```
cp -al "$oldname" "$newname"
unlink "$oldname"
```

should avoid any copying as long as $oldname and $newname are on the same mountpoint (filesystem).

---

You're in luck.

Solaris (with ZFS) is one of the very few filesystems that *actually* honour a creation time property for files.

Now on topic: No you cannot preserve all times: the inode will change and the filename changes. This means that the inode ctime will change by (POSIX) definition.

Your last accessed time will also change, unless you're running a noatime mount point (zfs set atime=off).

I don't think there is a way to change that. However, the file creation date time should not be changed at all. *I was going to show the commands to show creation times, but unfortunately I don't have a Solaris box handy and I can't seem to find it. I think your best bet is `man ls find stat`.*

GL

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use `cp -p` and then remove the original.

Comment: Thanks for that, really quick answer too

Comment: @user185572 There are performance implications.. If the file is big you might want to record the times and then use `touch(1)` to alter them back.

Answer (score 0):

The touch command can force the file modification time, but I am not sure this works with ZFS. If you are renaming large files this is lower overhead than cp -p. Here is a bash script:

```
oldFileTime=`find "$1" -maxdepth 0 -printf "%Ty%Tm%Td%TH%TM.%.2TS"`
mv "$1" "$2"
touch -t "$oldFileTime" "$2"
```